# Objective-C : How to read JSON in JSON?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

**I had JSON like this:**

```
 {
       "destination_addresses" : [ "Dimitrov, Phnom Penh, Cambodia" ],
       "origin_addresses" : [ "Tchecoslovaquie, Phnom Penh, Cambodia" ],
       "rows" : [
          {
             "elements" : [
                {
                   "distance" : {
                      "text" : "0.6 km",
                      "value" : 594
                   },
                   "duration" : {
                      "text" : "2 mins",
                      "value" : 100
                   },
                   "status" : "OK"
                }
             ]
          }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    }
```

**Here is my code:**

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init]; 
NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:apiResponse error:nil]; 
NSLog(@"Data = %@",data);

// getting the data from inside of "rows"  
NSDictionary *rows = (NSDictionary *) [data objectForKey:@"rows"];  
NSLog(@"Row = %@",rows);

NSDictionary *element = (NSDictionary *) [rows objectForKey:@"elements"];
NSLog(@"elements = %@",element);

NSDictionary *distance = (NSDictionary *) [rows objectForKey:@"distances"];
NSLog(@"Distance = %@",distance);
```

**But got error**:

> -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a9afa0 with  NSDictionary *element = (NSDictionary
>   *) [rows objectForKey:@"elements"];

I want to get **value in distance key**!

Answer (score 2):

If you carefully observe, `rows` is a dictionary inside a array.

```
"rows" : [
          {
             "elements" : [
                {
                   "distance" : {
                      "text" : "0.6 km",
                      "value" : 594
                   },
                   "duration" : {
                      "text" : "2 mins",
                      "value" : 100
                   },
                   "status" : "OK"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
```

So you need to do

```
NSArray *rows          = [data objectForKey:@"rows"];  
NSDictionary *rowsDict = [rows objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *element = [rowsDict objectForKey:@"elements"];
NSLog(@"elements = %@",element);

NSDictionary *distance = [[element objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"distances"];
NSLog(@"distance= %@", distance);
```

So on & so forth.

```
NSLog(@"Distance = %@",distance);
```